# USB Wifi Dongle not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, usb

I have a USB wifi dongle that I am trying to use with an old HP tower that I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on (light install).

lsusb shows:
`Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter`
for the device in question. It shipped with a Windows version of a RTL8812BU driver. There are also Linux drivers available on the manufacturer website (http://www.wise-tiger.com/English/html/2731985548.html).

I tested the dongle on a laptop running 16.04 and got it to work using the manufacturer-provided driver with only minor difficulty.

The drivers are outdated, but I manually patched them for 20.04 and the installer seems to run fine now, but I still don't see wifi networks available.

I realize there are numerous similar questions, so I've tried solutions from those. The most promising seemed to be getting the driver from here: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu. I followed those instructions without error, but still got no wifi connection after a reboot.

When I look at Settings > Network there isn't even an option for wireless.

ifconfig output:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::3350:e196:1b67:13b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:46:a0:9b:5d:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34152  bytes 15533511 (15.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16952  bytes 2227272 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3110  bytes 313665 (313.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3110  bytes 313665 (313.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

lshw -C network:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 74:46:a0:9b:5d:33
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

(wired works fine).

rfkill list returns no output.

Not seeing wlan0 or something equivalent at all seems odd to me. Any new ideas welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can install drivers from [Cilynx's GitHub repo for RTL88x2BU](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU) that has worked well for me.

As detailed in the repo, I've installed the drivers using [DKMS installation](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU#dkms-installation) method:

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, this but same outcome as the other drivers I've tried. I still don't see any options to even attempt a wifi connection. I think my issue must be elsewhere in configuration since all these drivers appear to install just fine.

Comment: @max-poschmann what's the `Device ID` you get when you run `lsusb`. In my case it's `2357:012d`, and full string looks like: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:012d TP-Link Archer T3U [Realtek RTL8812BU]`. Thanks.

Comment: 0bda:b812. I looked here: https://deviwiki.com/wiki/0bda and it says "Realtek RTL8812BU Wireless 802.11ac 2x2 USB 3.0". Thus I think I have been using the correct driver version. This is further corroborated by me using that driver version successfully on 3 other machines.